# in Java I have to check if a given matrix is a latin square or not

Tags: java, matrix, latin-square

my teacher has given us a matrix and we are supposed to write a code that checks if it is a latin square or not.  I have all of the pieces but I am having trouble putting them in order so they work.
this is what she has given us to read the matrix she has created.

The text file is matrix.txt, here is what it contains.

3

1 2 3

3 1 2

2 3 1

As you can see this is a latin square, however, she said we can change the matrix to make sure it works with the other problems she gave us.

```
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.util.Scanner;
     public class Multidim {

public static void main(String args[]){
    int matrix[][] = initMatrix();
    //printData(matrix); //Uncomment to print array

    /////YOUR MAIN CODE HERE/////



}

///PLACE YOUR METHODS HERE

public static int[][] initMatrix(){
    int matrix[][];
    Scanner filein = null;
    try {
        filein = new Scanner(new File("matrix.txt"));
        int numRows = Integer.parseInt(filein.nextLine());
        matrix = new int[numRows][];
        parseData(matrix, filein);
        filein.close();
        return matrix;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        if(filein != null)
            filein.close();
        return null;
    }
}

public static void parseData(int matrix[][], Scanner in){
    for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++){
        String splitLine[] = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        matrix[r] = new int[splitLine.length];
        for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++){
            matrix[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[c]);
        }
    }
}

public static void printData(int matrix[][]){
    for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++){
            System.out.print(matrix[r][c] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

This is the code I have currently. Where does it go?

```
    public static boolean LatinSquare(int[][]array) {
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++)  {
           if(i!=j)   {
               return false;
           }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
public boolean DuplicatesInRows(int[][]array) {
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)  {
        for (int j=0;j<array[i].length; j++) {
            int num=array[i][j];
            for(int col =j+1; col<array.length; col++) {
                if(num==array[i][col])  {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
   }
public boolean DuplicatesInCol(int[][]array) {
    for(int i=0;i<array.length; i++)  {
        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++)  {
            for(int k=1; k<array.length; k++)  {
                if (array[i][j+k]==array[i][j])  {
                    if (array[i][j]!=0)  {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

And I have no idea where this goes either...

```
  if(LatinSquare(matrix)==false)
  System.out.println("This is not a Latin Square");
  else
  System.out.println("This is a Latin Square");
```

Comment: You need to provide the "matrix.txt" file or input file format

Comment: how do I give you the matrix.txt file? it is just a 3x3 matrix that is a latin square if you want to create your own matrix.txt file.

Comment: add it in the question, with the proper line breaks

Comment: ok I added it to the question but am not sure I did it correctly.  Please let me know.

Comment: Please accept my accept my answer by clicking the green check box under the voting arrows, if it satisfies your question.

Comment: Please see my comment on the below answer in response to your question

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it

**Multidim.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Multidim 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int matrix[][] = initMatrix();
        // printData(matrix); //Uncomment to print array
        if(latinSquare(matrix))
        {
            System.out.println("This is a Latin Square");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("This is not a Latin Square");          
        } 
    }

    public static boolean latinSquare(int[][] array) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<array.length ;i++) 
        {
            // check for duplicates in each row
            if(duplicates(array[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // create a column array
            int[] column = new int[array[i].length]; 
            for(int j = 0; j<array.length; j++)
            {
                column[j] = array[j][i]; // could throw an exception if the input file isn't square 3x3, 2x2, 4x4, etc
            }

            // check for duplicates in each column
            if(duplicates(column))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean duplicates(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<array.length; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && array[i] == array[j])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }    
        }
        return false;
    }

    ///PLACE YOUR METHODS HERE
    public static int[][] initMatrix()
    {
        int matrix[][];
        Scanner filein = null;
        try 
        {
            filein = new Scanner(new File("matrix.txt"));
            int numRows = Integer.parseInt(filein.nextLine());
            matrix = new int[numRows][];
            parseData(matrix, filein);
            filein.close();
            return matrix;
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            if(filein != null)
            {
                filein.close();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void parseData(int matrix[][], Scanner in)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++)
        {
            String splitLine[] = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            matrix[r] = new int[splitLine.length];
            for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++)
            {
                matrix[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(splitLine[c]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printData(int matrix[][])
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**matrix.txt**

```
3
1 2 3
3 1 2
2 3 1
```

Note that your methods should follow [Oracle's code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#15423)

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

That is why I changed `LatinSquare` to `latinSquare`

Comment: thank you for your help. however, when I tried this with another matrix to test it and make sure it was correct, it did not work.  No matter what matrix I used, it said it was a Latin Square even when it wasn't. Is this because the first part that has the system.out.println before all of the booleans were done?

Comment: Can you give me the the test cases that is not working for you? I have tested it with non Latin squares. Changing the first row from `1 2 3` to `1 2 1` resulted in `This is not a Latin Square`. Also, Java is asynchronous, unless you spawn a new thread. The booleans will be returned first always.

Comment: I may have typed it in wrong, I will look.  the matrix I used was a 3x3 {123}{321}{231}.  I will try again

Comment: OK, I cheated and did a copy paste to make sure I didn't mistype anything and it worked. So thanks.  Now I would like to be able to have the program identify where the problem is in a non latin square. such as if it is in column 2 row 2.  Is this possible?

Comment: @LisaS I will restrain myself from doing your entire homework assignment. That was not your original question posted. I will give you a clue, yes it is possible, look at the index variables (`i`, `j`) used. Those are counting the current position of the array that is being inspected.

Comment: thank you that is what I thought but was unsure. However that is not the assignment.  I just wanted to know if it was possible because I believe it will be on the test.

Comment: @LisaS Please accept my answer if it meets your needs